# GfI receptacle Installed on same circuit as a circuit already being AFC I and GFCI protected

Tags: electrical

On a single circuit I already have an AFCI/GFCI breaker.  An inspector is making me put GFCI receptacles on the same circuit.
Is this really necessary?

Comment: Unless you can find someone over him, need to obey him.

Comment: If you have customers your question is not appropriate for this site. It is for DIY only.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a contractor asking about commercial work, not a DIYer.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, it's your mistake.

The locations that require GFCI protection either need

- an obvious GFCI receptacle, or
- labeling saying "GFCI Protected" which is telling the truth.

Also if there is no ground here, you need labeling saying "No Equipment Ground" and that is very important to passing inspection. It will explain why their GFCI testers don't work lol.

Your receptacle has neither, because like 99% of Americans you threw the ugly blue stickers in the trash.  Lacking that, it is in violation, and your inspector is correct for writing it up.

The labeling does not need to be ugly, nor blue, nor a sticker.  It can be anything that is not handwritten.  Laser etch the cover plate, a tasteful P-touch label on a white cover plate, whatever floats your boat.

Bonus points if it states where the reset is located.